# How to assign the same method to multiple delegates

Tags: c#, events, delegates, action, eventhandler

Is it possible to assign the same method to multiple delegates all at once?

```
public class Hoge
{        
    public event Action EventA;
    public event Action EventB;
    public event Action EventC;

    public Hoge()
    {
        EventA += () => FugaMethod();
        EventB += () => FugaMethod();
        EventC += () => FugaMethod();
    }

    private void FugaMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello.");
    }

}
```

I'd like to simplify the assignments of the FugaMethod().

Comment: Would you mind showing code you like to see? "Simplify" has different meaning to different people... (Also I don't think you can get better than `EventA += FugaMethod;` as generally there is no "assign to multiple objects at the same time" syntax in C#)

Comment: In case of variables, we can do `int a,b,c,d,e; a=b=c=d=e=1;` Is it possible to do similar things to events?

Comment: I see - I guess you can call it "assign multiple objects at the same time"... No such syntax for adding events I know of. DarkSquirrel42 - have way more details in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since events can't go as a parameter ... unfortunately ... no

if we are talking about a shitload of events, reflection would be the way to go ... but that i'd not really call "simplification"

edit:

for clarification:

what you can pass as a parameter:

the current list of eventhandlers attached to a static or specific event on a specific object (what you pass in this case is not the event, but a `MulticastDelegate`)

what you can not pass as a parameter: the event itself ...

you are not able to pass an event in a direct way that would allow to attach another event handler ... for that you would probably want to pass the specific obect instance, the `EventInfo` describing the event itself, and the new handler(s) ...

regarding "simplification":

what you need to do would be:

-use reflection to obtain the `EventInfo` objects of the desired events
-for each instance and each EventInfo call EventInfo.AddEventHandler, passing the instance as target and the eventhandler as handler

since you cannot pass the event as a parameter, you cannot extract a simple and typesafe method to get the desired EventInfo objects. you will have to use some selection by name, or other logic that takes the instance type apart by using Type.getEvent or Type.getEvents

so, if you are not handling a shitload of events, like a few hundred, writing it like you did seems to be the preferable way to go ... the reflection approach will be anything but simpler or shorter

Comment: what do you mean by "events can't go as a parameter". Events are delegates, and they can be passed in as method parameters.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez "Events are delegates" is not quite true - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx . Would you mind to show code that passes event EventA itself (not the current list of handlers) to a method? (indeed answer is somewhat strange).

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I might have used the word "simplify" in an inappropriate way. I just want to assign the FugaMethod to the 3 events all at once.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's why I asked for clarification. you can certainly do `foo(MyEvent);`, but you're right, the answer is probably talking about the input parameter being an event (not a delegate type) that you can add handlers to.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 yes, definitely.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Thank you very much for your detailed and precise explanation. Now I completely understand what I can and cannot do with events.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to assign multiple event handlers at once that does not require reflection however itäs not trivial and some programming is necessary. You can use a dictionary to store your events if you want initialize them in a loop.

*As a side note: by convention the `event` keyword should only be used if the delegate is of type `EventHandler`. It may and probably will confuse others when they try to use it.*

`Hoge` class:

```
public class Hoge
{
    // A dictionary to store your events.
    private Dictionary<string, EventHandler> events = new Dictionary<string, EventHandler>()
    {
        { "EventA", null },
        { "EventB", null },
        { "EventC", null }
    };

    // Event add/remove accessors.
    public event EventHandler EventA
    {
        add
        {
            lock (events)
            {
                events["EventA"] += (EventHandler)events["EventA"] + value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (events)
            {
                events["EventA"] += (EventHandler)events["EventA"] - value;
            }
        }
    }

    // You can do the same for other events.
    public event EventHandler EventB;
    public event EventHandler EventC;

    public Hoge()
    {
        // Initialize events in a loop.
        foreach (var key in events.Keys.ToList())
        {
            events[key] += FugaMethod;
        }
    }

    // Raises EventA.
    public void RaiseEventA()
    {
        EventHandler handler;
        if (null != (handler = (EventHandler)events["EventA"]))
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    // Event handler.
    private void FugaMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello.");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Hoge().RaiseEventA();
    }
}
```

[How to: Use a Dictionary to Store Event Instances (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4ka55h8.aspx)

[Handling and Raising Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx)